# Determining Max Size Of Variadic Template Class Instance in Compile Time in C++

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I want to determine max size of following variadic template class instance in compile time.

```
template <typename... T>
class Foo
{
public:

    std::tuple<T...> params;
    void (*func)(T...);

    void save(T...args)
    {
        params=std::make_tuple(args...);
    }

    void call()
    {
        std::apply(func,params);
    }
};
```

I want to use this class as follow:

```
void testfoo1(int a,double b,double c,double d)
{
    std::cout<<a<<"--"<<b<<c<<d<<std::endl;
}

void testfoo2(int a,double b,double c,double d,int e,long long int f)
{
    std::cout<<a<<"--"<<b<<c<<d<<e<<f<<std::endl;
}
struct FooObject
{
    char buffer[MAX_SIZE_FOO_OBJECT];
};

int main()
{
    std::queue<FooObject> fooObjectBuffer;
    FooObject foo_temp;
    Foo<int,double,double,double> foo1;
    Foo<int,double,double,double,int,long long int> foo2;
    foo1.func=testfoo1;
    foo1.save(5,10.2,5.3,2.7);
    foo2.func=testfoo2;
    foo2.save(1,2,3,4,5,6);
    fooObjectBuffer.push(*reinterpret_cast<FooObject*>(&foo1));
    fooObjectBuffer.push(*reinterpret_cast<FooObject*>(&foo2));

    foo_temp=fooObjectBuffer.front();
    reinterpret_cast<decltype (foo1)*>(&foo_temp)->call();
    fooObjectBuffer.pop();
    fooObjectBuffer.front();
    foo_temp=fooObjectBuffer.front();
    reinterpret_cast<decltype (foo2)*>(&foo_temp)->call();
    fooObjectBuffer.pop();
}
```

I need to know MAX_SIZE_FOO_OBJECT value to do this in compile time.
What can I do to know MAX_SIZE_FOO_OBJECT value in compile time?

Comment: Whats wrong with `sizeof(Foo<int,double,double,double>)`?

Comment: Your type punning is UB...

Comment: `std::max(sizeof(T)...)`

Comment: But I can use another variant of Foo in design. For example, Foo<int,doube,std::string> or Foo<Bar,std::string,double> etc. I want push any of these object to fooObjectBuffer without any buffer overflow problem.

Comment: @overlord That's not possible.  You either picks one size, use a template so each unique `Foo` gets it's own buffer, or you do a different approach.

Comment: I updated question because of misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

It's a template; unless you provide some specific restriction on the various `T`s that can go in `Foo`, anyone can instantiate it with any type which can be a member of a `std::tuple` and otherwise fits your interface. The set of `T`s is unbounded and therefore unknowable. Which means any operation on the various possible `T`s (like computing the maximum size) is equally unknowable.

You can only know this if you have some fixed, bounded set of valid `T`s that you intend to use. Even with that, you would need a lot of template metaprogramming to compute the size of every `Foo` instantiated with every combination of this set of `T`s.

It's best to just avoid this altogether and do something much more type-safe. Or failing that, pick a maximum size you're comfortable with and just `static_assert` somewhere if someone tries to instantiate `Foo` with types that exceed this size.